# TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm getting this error when exporting interface and was hoping to get some insight in why this happens:

```
// Interfaces.ts
export interface PortDescription {
  tag?: 'CORE' | 'TRANSIT' | 'SRV';
  name?: string;
  comment?: string;
}
```

Warning thrown:
`TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.`

The code compiles without error or warnings and imports works fine so maybe it's just Webstorm giving me a hard time.

I've done the Google part but it did not yield any useful answers.

Comment: Is that... it?? That snippet of code would not produce that error. It's typical of mistyped arrays... but you have none.

Comment: Very good input. I'll see if I have something using the interface that is triggering this error.

Comment: I moved the code to a folder tracked by git in order to safely make some destructive changes and track when the problem disappeared. But after the move the issue was gone. Maybe Webstorm acting up. Thanks for the comment!